# How do I order by multiple columns in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table of records like below

```
int_record_id     int_category_id  str_name   int_order   bit_active
      1                 1            test1        2           1
      2                 1            test2        1           1
      3                 2            test3        1           1
      1                 3            test4        3           1
```

i want to select this record in a such a way that it should be sorted in the order of both `int_category_id` and `int_order`

so the result should be like below

```
int_record_id     int_category_id  str_name   int_order   bit_active
      2                 1            test2       1           1
      1                 1            test1       2           1      
      3                 2            test3       1           1     
      4                 3            test4       3           1
```

Does any one have an idea about its sql query, i have tried a lot i'm not getting the result correct.
can any one show me the exact sql query for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select * from your_table order by int_category_id, int_order
```

Answer (score 3):

This query should do:

```
select * from myTable
order by int_category_id, int_order
```

You need to decide what you primary sort will be and inside that the secondary (and so on).

So, if you want to sort first by order then by category, you would use:

```
select * from myTable
order by int_order, int_category_id
```

See the [mySql order by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) documentation.